# how to load array parameter in another shell file dynamically over ssh connection

Tags: bash, ssh

I need to call my executable which is placed in an on-prem server by using an ssh connection and pass a dynamics parameter.
based on my requirement, users should be able to add or remove parameters as they want to work with the executable on the on-prem server.

I wrote a translator to identify any new parameter added to the console but now when I want to pass it via ssh, I am facing 2 problems.

1. what if I have a value that contains space?
2. how to load these values dynamically & use them as arguments on my shell script on the server?

**Also take note that I am sending some additional parameters that are not related to my executable argument but I need them as well.

> ```
> params=(
>     "$MASTER"
>     "$NAME"
>     "$QUEUE"
>     service.enabled=true
> )
>
> for var_name in "${!conf__@}";
> do
>         key=${var_name#conf__};
>         key=${key//_/.};
>         value=${!var_name};
>         params+=( --conf "$key=$value" );
> done
> echo "${params[@]}"
>
> ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myuser@server_ip "/bin/bash -s" < deploy_script.sh "${params[@]}"
> ```

My **deploy_script.sh** file will be something like the below file.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
AR_MASTER=${1}
AR_NAME=${2}
AR_QUEUE=${3}
AR_SER_EN=${4}
# How can I get the other dynamic parameters???
main() {
my-executable \
    "--master "$AR_MASTER \
    "--name "$AR_NAME \
    "--queue "$AR_QUEUE \
    "--conf service.enabled="$AR_SER_EN \
    ??? #how to add the additional configuration dynamically?
 }
 main "$@"
```

Would you mind help me in figure it out?

Comment: You are constrained with the limitations of bash arguments processing.  Spaces?  Surround the argument with `"`.   There is no support for arrays as arguments, only text.

Comment: @Nic3500: multi-line also not supported? I mean I should convert everything in single line?

Comment: Indeed.  Bash processes arguments like text.  Each work is another argument, and new lines are not supported, unless you quote and backslash special characters.  It can be a pain.  Easier to read from file.  The arguments processing is done by the shell from which you call your executable, so you are constrained by its limitations.